# How does Windows keeps track of the size of VirtualAllocdBlocks?

Tags: windows, heap-memory, windbg

I wonder how windows keeps track of the size of the "VirtualAllocdBlocks". According to WinDBG the memory blocks are managed in doubly linked lists. But this struct (_LIST_ENTRY) only contains two pointer. How can I get the size (in WinDBG) of such a block and where is the size stored in memory?

```
0:008> dt _HEAP 0x00150000 
ntdll!_HEAP
   ...
   +0x050 VirtualAllocdBlocks : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0x3e40000 - 0x13950000 ]
   ...
0:008> dt _LIST_ENTRY 0x3e40000 
ntdll!_LIST_ENTRY
 [ 0x3f50000 - 0x150050 ]
   +0x000 Flink            : 0x03f50000 _LIST_ENTRY [ 0x4050000 - 0x3e40000 ]
   +0x004 Blink            : 0x00150050 _LIST_ENTRY [ 0x3e40000 - 0x13950000 ]
```

Comment: I think you'll find the list contains the entire virtual memory space, presumably in order, so the size of block `ptr` is `ptr->Flink - ptr`.

Comment: Actually, the size might not be needed in this structure by the heap manager, since you call [VirtualFree()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualfree) with 0 for dwSize. But I'd at least expect to find the base addresses.